# Why is Postman giving me the error 'Cannot POST' for my routes in express app?

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I am using Postman to test my function and am using POST to send the request. Every time I send it, I get the error: 'Cannot POST /translate'. I added the code below for my route and function:

```
 app.post('/translate'), async function(request, response) {
   const translatedText = await translateText(request)
   res.json(translatedText)
}

  async function translateText(request) {
    const text = request.body['text']
    const language = request.body['language']

    let [translations] = await translate.translate(text, language)
    translations = Array.isArray(translations) ? translations : [translations]
    return translations
  }
```

Comment: what's the postman `url` ?

Comment: Using localhost so it’s localhost:3000/translate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've misused the `app.post` method. First you create the url, as you have done, but then it requires a callback method **inside** the method parameters.

```
// remove ) after '/translate'
app.post('/translate', async function(request, response) {
   const translatedText = await translateText(request)
   res.json(translatedText)
});
```

from the [express docs](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html):

> Route definition takes the following structure: `app.METHOD(PATH, HANDLER)` Where:
>
> - app is an instance of express.
> - METHOD is an HTTP request method, in lowercase.
> - PATH is a path on the server.
> - HANDLER is the function executed when the route is matched.